# Express / MYSQL request JOIN users & messages

Tags: mysql

I have this 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `messages`
(
`id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sender_id` INT NOT NULL,
`receiver_id` INT NOT NULL,
`message` VARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`is_read` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES users (id),
FOREIGN KEY (`receiver_id`) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

and i want to SELECT the users to whom I have sent a message or who have sent me a message.

For that, i have create a controller who have my userId in query request :

```
static getAllWithMessages(req, res) {
    UsersModel.findAllBy(
      [req.query.userId, req.query.userId, req.query.userId],
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send(results);
      }
    );
  }
```

and try this select :

```
db.query(
      "SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email FROM users RIGHT JOIN messages AS messages_send ON (users.id = messages_send.sender_id) RIGHT JOIN messages AS messages_received ON (users.id = messages_received.receiver_id) WHERE users.id <> ? AND (messages_send.receiver_id = ? OR messages_received.sender_id = ?) GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY name ASC ",
      where,
      callback
    );
```

but i have only users who send me message. I don't know how to add users whom i have sent a message...
I know my request is very bad :(

If you have some ideas :)

thanks

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN... and in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.name, users.email
FROM messages
JOIN users ON users.id IN (messages.sender_id, messages.receiver_id)
WHERE @your_id IN (messages.sender_id, messages.receiver_id);
```

where `@your_id` is the ID of the user whose interlocutors you need to find.

Comment: @Strawberry mmm.. I cannot understand your idea. Can you say the same but more detailed?

Comment: @Strawberry As I understand this condition realizes "those user and not me" logic. In my query I cover this (each pair contains "me" as one of participants), so this unequiation is excess.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it

Comment: Yeah thank you very much !! I just have to add a condition to not include @yourId in the results but it's great! My request was really wrong!